# How is the invert overlay effect done in css?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at the Nike website and I cannot understand how the inverted scroll effect is achieved with css.

When scrolling on this website - https://www.swoosh.nike/ - you can see the join and the svg logo become inverted based on the background color, here's a picture of the effect to incase the website changes for future reference:

[image: nike website inverted colors scroll]

How do they achieve this effect. I can't see any css that tells the colors in the svg or button to become inverted on background color.

Comment: Please edit your question with a working code example of what you have tried the outline your specific challenge with that.  Asking us to decipher how some site works is really perhaps out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire Header-Element has

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

set in CSS.